# How to setting parameters dynamically in js with async?

Tags: javascript

I'm a Java developer,I want to set value:symbol dynamically,but div("tradingview-widget-container__widget") always not work,can you help me?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='viewport'
          content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" value="COINBASE:BTCUSD" id="symbol"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol").value;
     </script>
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="background-color:#2A2D38">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a
            href="https://www.tradingview.com/" rel="noopener"
            target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Data</span></a> by TradingView
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-single-quote.js" async="">
        console.log("wdiget:"+symbol);
        {
            "symbol"
        :
            symbol,
                "width"
        :
            "100%",
                "colorTheme"
        :
            "dark",
                "isTransparent"
        :
            false,
                "locale"
        :
            "en"
        }
    </script>
    <!-- </div> -->
    <!-- <div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="background-color:#2A2D38"> -->

    <div id="tradingview_b59ae" style="background-color:#2A2D38"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("chart:"+symbol);
        new TradingView.widget(
            {
                "autosize": true,
                "symbol": symbol,
                "interval": "D",
                "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
                "theme": "Dark",
                "style": "3",
                "locale": "en",
                "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
                "enable_publishing": false,
                "withdateranges": true,
                "save_image": false,
                "container_id": "tradingview_b59ae"
            }
        );

    </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
</body>
</html>
```

when I run it in chrome,console does not log `console.log(symbol);`,but div("tradingview_b59ae") get the symbol value.So how to deal with this problem with async div?

---

I use SpringBoot thymeleaf(Java) to modify `"<input type="hidden" value="COINBASE:BTCUSD" id="symbol"/>"`'s value,when client need this page,Java will set the value and post page to client,but `"console.log("wdiget:"+symbol);"`not work,`"console.log("chart:"+symbol);"` is work.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make out the question, I have no idea what you mean by *"...does not log console.log(symbol);,but div("tradingview_b59ae") get the symbol value."* But there is an error apparent in the question: A `script` element's contents (the text between `<script ...>` and `</script>` are **not executed** if the `script` tag has a `src`. (They're considered "script documentation", not code.) Separately, what's in the code that isn't executed would have a syntax error if it *were* treated as code, as of the first `:`. (cont'd)

Comment: (continuing) As of the code at the end, `symbol` should be the value from the hidden input. That's an awkward way to get that value (via the hidden input), but it does work. Finally, note that there's no need whatsoever for `type="text/javascript"` on a `script` tag. That's the default on all browsers going back well over a decade.